# Why do I need to sudo to use leiningen (installed in /bin) on Linux?

Tags: linux, clojure, fedora, leiningen

I installed leiningen on fedora, I followed the instruction:

1. download the script
2. Paste the script(via command line) to ~/bin (PATH)
3. Execute the script
4. Run lein(I had to did it with sudo) to self-install

but every time I want to run the "lein" command, I have to do it with "sudo".

How can i fix this? or what can i do to fix this?

**Note:** I installed leiningen at /bin but when i cd ~/bin as the installation guide said i get and error about the folder(not exist).

Comment: If it's at **`/bin`**, that's a folder owned by root and it would make (some) sense that you have to have escalated privileges to run it.  If it's at **`~/bin`**, that should be in your own home folder.  What does `which lein` tell you?

Comment: @Makoto: I'd suggest `type lein` rather than `which lein`; the latter is an external command and doesn't know about shell aliases, functions, or the like, whereas the former is a builtin and has visibility into everything considered in the shell's execution process (including caching of prior PATH lookups, making it more accurate even for something known to be an external command).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You installed it in `/bin` and ran it with sudo to install the lein jars initially, which means they are owned (and probably only readable) by root. You should install the script at `~/bin` instead. You can fix it like this:

```
sudo rm /bin/lein
sudo rm ~/.lein
mkdir ~/bin
cd ~/bin
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein
export PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
lein
```

You should also add `${HOME}/bin` to your `$PATH`. If you are using bash, add this to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
```

You can do that using `echo`:

```
echo 'export PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: how can i add the last line? (I am a linux beginner, sorry)

Comment: Ideally, changes to the PATH should go in `.bash_profile`, not `.bashrc`. In the `.bashrc`, they'll be reapplied for every new shell even after being applied in the login shell that's its parent, thus you'll end up with `PATH=$HOME/bin:$HOME/bin:$HOME/bin:...` after multiple nested shells are invoked.

Comment: ...if you're going to keep it in the `.bashrc`, then at least add some safeties; for instance: `[[ $PATH =~ (^|:)"$HOME/bin"(:|$) ]] || PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Note that the `export` isn't necessary here (though it doesn't harm anything): It flags a variable to be exported to the environment, but PATH is already an environment variable by the time an interactive user's dotfiles are being executed, so the `export` has no effect.

Comment: I tried your solution but i still get the permission message, how can i delete the lein instalation ?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: True, but most Linux distros won't invoke `~/.bash_profile` when running a GUI terminal (such as Konsole).

Comment: after trying with sudo lein it said lein does not exist

Comment: Also, don't use sudo at all (after the first two steps); you don't need to use sudo with lein if you install it using the given directions.